# display a png picture and hold it for 3 seconds in R

Tags: r, user-interface, png

I am very new to user interface using R. I have a png file. I would like to display it at the beginning of my script, keep it to stay for around 3 seconds and close it automatically.

I tried file.show(). R will pop the png file. But that is not what I want.

I prefer to make it appear in front of my IDE like a splash screen that appears before a program starts. I mean it will be similar to a welcome pic before the user really start to run the script. After 3 seconds, it will disappear and R will start to run the script automatically.

I wonder any R package can make my idea come true? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with displaying it? Simply make it appear in front of your IDE/Prompt? Like a splash screen that appears before a program starts?

Comment: @Molx: Yes. That is what I mean. Make it appear in front of my IDE like a splash screen that appears before a program starts. I am going to edit my question and make it more clear. Thank you

Comment: I don't think you'll find a reasonable solution to this (it is easy enough to make it appear on the plot area), this isn't the kind of feature R is intended to have.

Comment: @Molx: that is just my idea. If R can not work, it is OK. Thank you so much for your reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably could get you started. The image will appear in the default RStudio bottom-right panel for 3 seconds and then will disappear. Warning: `dev.off()` will erase all your plots that you had in workspace before running the script.

```
#At the very beginning of the script, execute:
library(png)
img <- readPNG("path/baboon.png")
windows()
grid::grid.raster(img)
Sys.sleep(3)
dev.off()

#... your script continues here
print("Did you see that baboon??")
```

Edit: `windows()` does exactly what you need, I think

Comment: Though it is not what I am looking for, it is also good to know. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you are on Windows, `windows()` before plotting the PNG does exactly what you want. Check it out, please

Comment: yes. I use windows. The png file exists in my system. it is not a plot from R. I would like to show it to user before the main script run. any idea? thank you

Comment: OK. The above code should work. I used a random png picture, and R opens a separate window and shows the baboon for 3 seconds, then continues with the main code

Comment: yes. it works. I am so excited. Thanks for your help :)